# Is there any way to retrieve bytes from an iframe whose src is a pdf blob?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have a web page with an iframe and a number of cards representing client submissions to an online form. When the user clicks a submission, the following things occur:

- Using pdf-lib, a local PDF file is loaded.
- The fillable fields of this PDF are populated with the submission data.
- Then, we save the bytes and create a blob and url.
- Finally, the iframe has its src set to this url.

The whole process looks something like this:

```js
const src = "{{ pdf path here}}.pdf";
const existingBytes = await fetch(src).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());

const doc = await PDFDocument.load(existingBytes);
const form = doc.getForm();
fillSubmittedInformation(form, data); // This function just fills form fields.

const bytes = await doc.save();const blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/pdf" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const preview = document.getElementById("pdf") as HTMLIFrameElement;
preview.src = url;
```

The user can then edit the content of the fillable fields of the PDF through the iframe, which will be using their browser's native PDF viewer. What I would like to do is to then be able to get the bytes of the PDF when the user clicks a button, and use them. Specifically once the user is done I'd like to flatten the form and download the PDF, but the specifics aren't really important.

Unfortunately, after a few hours of searching I have come up short. Many online sources suggest accessing `preview.contentWindow.document`, but this results in an exception since blob urls are considered as separate origins. [This](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/1312) thread would seem to suggest that it is not possible with an iframe, and instead suggest to use Adobe's API, but I'd like to avoid a rate limited 3rd party dependency. I have also tried with an embed but to no success. While online sources have not yielded a working solution, I can't see why something this simple would have no native solution. I would just like to know if this is feasible, and perhaps a point in the right direction.

Put simply:
Given an iframe whose `src` is a blob url and whose content has been manipulated, (how) can I retrieve it's current byte data?

Comment: I guess perhaps I should clarify this, as I forgot to mention it in the question. I did see that solution, but I'd rather avoid a 3rd party dependency if possible, especially one that has a usage limit. I'm just surprised that there is no native way to do this.

Also I'm not sure what you mean when you say that my question "clearly implies the file is offline", perhaps you could clarify? It is an iframe linking to blob url created in JavaScript being viewed inside a webpage? They cannot to edit outside the browser if they want to, or at least I do not intend to support such actions.

Comment: So, to clarify, you believe this is simply not possible with a simple iframe or embed?

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help. I've been thinking pdf.js was my best bet, I think this is the approach I will pursue.